# jsPDF addImage not working

Tags: javascript, pdf, callback, jspdf, todataurl

I am using jsPDF to create a PDF by looping through some HTML code to find the values it needs. I am able to get the values just fine, but when I try to insert the `header_img` it does not work. I have found many solutions on Google but the one I am working with now is the only one that does not throw an error.

This is the code being used to get take the url that is provided via the loop, convert it to a DataURL, and then insert the image into the PDF. It does not give me any errors, but all that is in the PDF is the black border and no image. Any ideas?

```js
function getDataUri(url, cb) {
 var image = new Image();
 image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous'); //getting images from external domain

 image.onload = function () {
  console.log(url);
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; 

  //next three lines for white background in case png has a transparent background
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';  /// set white fill style
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

  cb(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
 };

 image.src = url;
}

var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
 

var left_margin = .5;
var top_margin =.5;
var height = 2.313;
var width = 3.25;
var header_img_height = 1;

//Draw border
pdf.setLineWidth(1/92);
pdf.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
pdf.rect(left_margin, top_margin, width, height);
 
//example image
var header_img = 'http://www.quotehd.com/imagequotes/authors24/jeff-olsen-quote-two-clicks-and-its-broke.jpg';
 
let logo = null;

//callback to get DataURL
getDataUri(header_img, function(dataUri) {
 logo = dataUri;
 console.log("logo=" + logo);
 
  //Add image to PDF
 pdf.addImage(logo, 'JPEG', left_margin, top_margin, header_img_height, width);
});

pdf.output('save', 'test.pdf');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by writing a PHP script that would convert the image to Base64.

```
$img_src = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$img_str = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_src));
echo 'data:' . getimagesize($img_src)['mime'] . ';base64,' . $img_str;
```

Then using jQuery, I passed the url to the PHP script and got the Base64 data in return:

```
function getBase64(url) {

    var out = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get-dataurl.php?url=' + encodeURI(url),
        async: false,
        dataTye: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            out = data;
        }
  });
    return out;
}
```

Certainly was not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the image to base64, you would use [this tool](http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image) or any similar and replace it on your code.

Comment: While that would work, I am trying to do it locally as this script will be on a local server and not always have access to the internet. Additionally, the script runs through a loop and the header_img variable is assigned within the loop. The image is not constant.

Comment: I gave it a shot anyway, and when using the Base64 image output, it still does not add the image.

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of trying to figure it out why I couldn't display a simple image in my PDF I finally found the solution.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var img = new Image;
    img.src = "my-image.png";
    img.onload = function() {
        doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 10, 10);
        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
    };
```

So there were 2 tricks here, the first one was that I should wait for the image to load and only after that to add it to the PDF. I found this on several other places also. However, the final solution was to output or save the PDF in the same onload method. If you try to save or output the pdf outside that onload method, your image won't be added to the PDF.